# Change cursor to wait while the angular $apply is running

Tags: angularjs, performance, mouse-cursor

I have a complicated page with a lot of nested ng-repeat. The $apply function can take several seconds. During that time the browser is hung and the user cannot do anything.

As a courtesy I would like to change the mouse pointer to hourglass while $apply is running.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to change the cursor (using addClass), then invoke the slow code with a timeout at the end of which you change the cursor back to normal.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/Lna6LyeL/33/)

```
    var mybody = angular.element(document).find('body');
    mybody.addClass('waiting');   // set cursor to hourglass
    setTimeout(function() {
        doSlowStuff();
        $scope.$apply();
        mybody.removeClass('waiting');  // set cursor to normal
    }, 0);
```

You have to do the slow stuff in a timeout so that the `addClass` will be applied before the slow stuff starts.

The CSS is just

```
.waiting { cursor: wait; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ng-class` directive to set classes and `ng-disabled` to disable buttons:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl"
     ng-class="{waiting: status=='running'}">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    <button ng-click="more();" ng-disabled="status=='running'">
    CLICK HERE
    </button> {{status}}
```

Use the `$timeout` service which is integrated with the AngularJS digest cycle:

```
$scope.more = function() {
    //var mybody = angular.element(document).find('body');
    //mybody.addClass('waiting');
    $scope.status = 'running';
    //setTimeout(function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        doSlowStuff();
        $scope.status = 'done';
        //$scope.$apply();
        //mybody.removeClass('waiting');
    }, 1000);
};
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gd9e72hw/)

Comment: This is certainly a more elegant solution.  However using $timeout and ngClass is not very reliable for me. The cursor doesn't change sometimes. (I'm using chrome). Maybe in a future version of angular they will fix it.